# Sum fields from mutiple tables with conditions

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm working on a quite big project and I need to compute some values through SQL. I have 3 datasets with quite identical fields :

```
Query1 : txt groupName, int cat, long hoursSubTot1
Query2 : txt groupName, int cat, long hoursSubTot2
Query3 : txt groupName, int cat, long hoursSubTot3
```

I need to add hoursSubTot1,hoursSubTot2 and hoursSubTot3 like that :
[image]

I would like the datas to be agregate as shown in the result table. But I do not manage to agregate the right values in Access, I am out of ideas so any help or advice would be welcome...

Thanks!

Comment: Next time, add table data and result as text, not as images. Please!

Comment: Ok, sorry I thought it would have been clearer with a picture, I wont do that in future

Comment: I don't know Access that well. Can you do GROUP BY on a UNION ALL?

Comment: I know that I can make `GROUP BY` but I have never used `UNION` statement. But I just checked and Access indeed allow `UNION`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not opposed to using multiple queries, here's my thought.  First create a query using `UNION ALL` to combine the three queries.  Then you can create a new query to calculate the sums.

```
SELECT Group, Category, Hours FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Group, Category, Hours FROM Table2
UNION ALL
SELECT Group, Category, Hours FROM Table3
```

Answer (score 1):

ANSI SQL answer, may or may not work for Access:

```
select group, category, sum(hours)
from
(
select group, category, hours from table1
union all
select group, category, hours from table2
union all
select group, category, hours from table3
)
group by group, category
```

Comment: indeed it worked, but I think I will use an intermediate query for the `UNION` table since Access seems to have trouble with subquery ! Thanks !